# Complex number sum 1

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $1, w_1, w_2, \cdots w_9$ be the distinct complex $10^{th}$ roots of unity.

Find $(1 − w_1) \cdots (1 − w_9) \sum_{j= 1}^9 \frac{1}{1-w_j}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), your question is hard to read right now.

Comment: @lhf I am finding it difficult to understand from the reference given by you.Can you help me please by writing down the steps.Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x-\omega_1)(x-\omega_2)\cdots (x-\omega_9)$.
Let $g(x)=f(x)\sum_{j=1}^{9} \dfrac{1}{x-\omega_j}$.

Then $g(x)=f'(x)$ and the value we want is $g(1)=f'(1)$.

Let $h(x)=(x-1)f(x)=x^{10}-1$.

Then $h''(x)=2f'(x)+(x-1)f''(x)$ and also of course $h''(x)=90x^8$.

Therefore $f'(1)=\dfrac12h''(1) = 45$.